# Qt Designer QListWidget checkbox

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4, qt-designer

I am using PyQt4 and Qt Designer. I have a `QListWidget` in which I populate after loading a file in my program.

I want to set it so that all items will be checkable, as opposed to just selectable. I have found online that this is a 'flag' of the `QListWidget`, however, in Qt Designer I can't see where to do this.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this by opening the edit list widget item tab , and look into the properties. and set the checkState property.

[image]

**UPDATE **

```
item = QtGui.QListWidgetItem()
item.setText(QtGui.QApplication.translate("Dialog", x, None,    QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
item.setFlags(item.flags() | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable)
item.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Unchecked)
self.listWidget.addItem(item)
```

Comment: okay i see that now, but thats only after you make an item.  I dont have any items in my list.  I populate the list after the program starts, so the checkboxes are not for individual items but for all items that will be in that listwidget

Comment: @user1938107 : share the code that you use to load the gui and  how you populate the itemwidget

Comment: i have a list widget, it is called myListwidget, and i populate it by self.myListwidget.addItem(someString)

Comment: so addItem just auto creates the QListWidgetItem() without needing to specify it but then doesnt allow for setting the flags?  It would make sense for qt to just have an option for all items in a list to be checkable upon creation

Answer (score 0):

The age-old question. There is an answer here, but I'll try to give some clarification: for several components there isn't enough to set item flag Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable, one needs to set item's check state for the checkbox to appear. Also, there is no widget flag to make all items checkable.

An excerpt from Qt documentation:

> Note that checkable items need to be given both a suitable set of
> flags and an initial state, indicating whether the item is checked or
> not. This is handled automatically for model/view components, but
> needs to be explicitly set for instances of QListWidgetItem,
> QTableWidgetItem, and QTreeWidgetItem.